# What is the php syntax for a REGEXP that changes "Last, First" into "Last..First"?

Tags: php, regex

I need to create a php search function for names and need to change LastName, FirstName into LastName..FirstName to search the database.  I don't know if this helps, but the string will originally be in the form a variable ($Client).

I need the syntax for the three statements that find the string, matches, and makes the changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'd like to use a regular expression:

```
$client = preg_replace('/,\s+/', '..', $client);
```

Regular expression explanation

```
,     ',' literal comma
\s+   followed by 1 or more whitespace characaters
```

---

All that being said, `str_replace` can do the trick if you will always have `"Doe, John"` (with one space)

Answer (score 2):

```
str_replace(', ', '..', $Client);
```

Answer (score 1):

Is

```
$name = str_replace(", ", "..", $name);
```

out of the question?